# Replacing only full words in a string with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace only the first occurrence of a word in a sentence with **regex**.

I want to replace only full words, and therefore exclude partial matches.

For example, in the sentence "The quick brown foxy fox jumps over the lazy dog", I would like to replace `fox` by `cat`.

The result that I could achieve was the following: "The quick brown caty fox jumps over the lazy dog". As opposed to `foxy cat`.

I am using the `Regex.Replace` method as follows:

```
var reg = new Regex(currentKeyword, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);

reg.Replace(input, replace, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correct regex, such as `@"\bcat\b"`.

Answer (score 7):

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\b" + currentKeyword + @"\b", ...);
```

The `\b` means a [word boundary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I marked wRAR as the correct answer as he was the first to post, but your explanation is the best one.